# Find value into List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>

Tags: java

I have a:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> myobj = {"idrow":1, "value":"test"}...;
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> list = more myobj;
```

For example if list contains:

```
idrow = 0;
value = test0;
idrow = 1;
value = test1;..
```

how can find a particular idrow (example 1) from list without value (field)?
Thanks.

Comment: You got it all wrong, friend. A hash map maps keys to values. And then there's your list of maps. And your map doesn't appear to map anything well, not if you try to map `value` by `idrow`, at least. Anyhow, I am not at all sure what are you trying to do. Better tell you intentions instead of posting code, or better yet illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the list of maps and get the first non-null occurrence of `map.get(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am convinced your code is deeply flawed, the pragmatic answer is:

```
for(HashMap<String, Object> map : list)
{
    if(!map.containsKey("value"))
    {
        return map.get("idrow"); /** Desired result */
    }
}
```

This is is close as you can get with your current description of the problem - the above will iterate through the list of maps, and retrieve the value mapped by the `idrow` key, when the map containing the said key does **not** contain `value` key-value pair. But as I read the last sentence, I am again convinced you need something ENTIRELY DIFFERENT ALTOGETHER.